# How can I tell if my laptop can do 4k resolution? (Using Linux Mint)

Tags: monitor, linux-mint, video-card

I am thinking about getting a new monitor. Short of plugging one in and seeing what happens, how can I tell if my laptop can output 4k resolution?
Is there a command I can run that will tell me this?

I thought maybe I could xrandr, but I think that only tells me what each monitor is capable of (even if the controller is capable of more.)

I also thought maybe I could look up the device from the `lspci` and find it on google, but I couldn't find much.

My `lspci -v` says:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 500d
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f3000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Update: Mr. Llama's suggestion about `xrandr` made me think that this output could be useful to someone who knows more than I do. Here's my xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5206 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384

eDP-1-0 connected 1366x768+0+0 309mm x 173mm
   1366x768       60.1*+
... other resolution options removed for brevity ...
   320x240        60.1  

HDMI-1-0 connected 1920x1080+3286+0 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
... other resolution options removed for brevity ...
   640x480        60.0     59.9  


DisplayPort-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
... other resolution options removed for brevity ...
   720x400        70.1  

VGA-1-0 disconnected
HDMI-1-1 disconnected
DisplayPort-1-0 disconnected
```

Comment: I finally got my 4k monitor, but my laptop won't support it. After experimenting with different ModeLines with xrandr, I was able to get 2560x1440 @ 30hz. The limiting factor was the graphics device's pixel-clock. It could only do 4k @ ~20hz, which the monitor detects, but won't display.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the `xrandr` command might be of use to you.  It lists the available and current monitor resolution.

See this [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/q/418699/245923) for more information.

Comment: I tried xrandr, but that seems to only tell me the maximum for the device that is connected to the controller (the monitor) and not the maximum that the video controller itself is capable of. Is there something that I'm missing?